# How do I perform a bitwise AND of two BIGNUMs?

Tags: c++, openssl, bignum

I'm working with the openssl `BIGNUM` library in C++.

The problem I have is that I need to compute the bitwise `and` of two `BIGNUM` values a and b, but I can't figure out how to do this. I searched the web for a while now, but I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

There is no bitwise and function for BIGNUM in OpenSSL. Here's how I do bitwise-and, you can use it until you find an adequate solution.

```
BN_ULONG bn_and_words(BN_ULONG *r, const BN_ULONG *a, const BN_ULONG *b, int n)
{
    BN_ULONG l,t;

    if (n <= 0) return((BN_ULONG)0);

    while(n)
    {
        t=a[0];
        l=(t&b[0]);
        l=(t&b[0])&BN_MASK2;
        r[0]=l;
        a++; b++; r++; n--;
    }
    return((BN_ULONG)*r);
}
```

The above internal function `bn_and_words` is used in this function:

```
int BN_bitwise_and(BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b)
{
    int max,min,dif;
    BN_ULONG *ap,*bp,*rp;
    const BIGNUM *tmp;

    bn_check_top(a);
    bn_check_top(b);

    if (a->used< b->used)
        { tmp=a; a=b; b=tmp; }
    max = a->used;
    min = b->used;
    dif = max - min;

    if (bn_wexpand(r,max+1) == NULL)
        return 0;

    r->used=max;

    ap=a->d;
    bp=b->d;
    rp=r->d;

    bn_and_words(rp,ap,bp,min);
    rp+=min;
    ap+=min;
    bp+=min;

    while (dif)
    {
        *(rp++) = *(ap++);
        dif--;
    }
    r->neg = 0;
    bn_check_top(r);
    return 1;
}
```

Result `r` of `a AND b` is the first argument and the return value of function `BN_bitwise_and`.

Here is a test:

```
int test_and()
{
    BIGNUM *a,*b,*r;
    a=BN_new();
    b=BN_new();
    r=BN_new();

    if (!BN_hex2bn(&a, "1234567890ABCDEF")) return -1;
    if (!BN_hex2bn(&b, "FEDCBA0987654321")) return -1;

    BN_bitwise_and(r,a,b);
    BN_print_fp(stdout, r);

    BN_free(a);
    BN_free(b);
    BN_free(r);
}
```

The result `r` printed on stdout is

```
1214120880214121
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's quiet surprising that this is not directly possible in openssl, but this looks great

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no function to do this directly, hence you'll have to come up with something based on the functionality that is there. Something like:

```
BIGNUM *a, *b, *result;
unsigned current = 0;

//Creation of a, b, result

while(!BN_zero(a) && !BN_zero(b)) {
    if(BN_is_bit_set(a, current) && BN_is_bit_set(b, current)) {
        BN_set_bit(result, current);
    } else {
        BN_clear_bit(result, current);
    }
    ++current;
    BN_rshift1(a, a);
    BN_rshift1(b, b);
}
```

Note that this may need to manually set the higher order bits to 0 if the bitlength of `a` is greater than `b` or vice-versa. It should be enough to get your started, however.